# Multiple subnets in same azure VNet with Terrafrom

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating 1 virtual network and 3 subnets using for_each loop.
I am geting error in creating subnets
[I have taken reference from this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006812/multiple-subnets-in-same-vnet-with-terrafrom) and tried to troubleshoot the issue but unable to fix the error.

Below is my code.

main.tf

```
 resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet01" {
  name                = "${var.env}-${var.vnetname}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.RG01Name.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG01Name.name
  address_space       = var.vnetaddspace
  dns_servers         = var.vnetdnsservers
  tags                = var.tags
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.RG01Name.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet01.name
}
```

variable.tf

```
    variable "vnetname" {
      type = string
    }
    variable "vnetaddspace" {
    }        
    variable "vnetdnsservers" {}                

    variable "subnets" {
    [![enter image description here][2]][2]type = map(object({
    name    = string
    address = string
  }))
}
```

dev.tfvars

```
vnetaddspace   = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
vnetdnsservers = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

subnets = {
  key1 = { name = "sub01", address = "10.13.1.0/24" }
  key2 = { name = "sub02", address = "10.13.2.0/24" }
  key3 = { name = "sub03", address = "10.13.3.0/24" }
}
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on NW.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet":
│   14:   address_prefixes     = each.value.address
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.address is "10.13.1.0/24"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "address_prefixes": list of string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on NW.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet":
│   14:   address_prefixes     = each.value.address
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.address is "10.13.2.0/24"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "address_prefixes": list of string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on NW.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet":
│   14:   address_prefixes     = each.value.address
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.address is "10.13.3.0/24"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "address_prefixes": list of string required.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list of strings, not string only:

```
address_prefixes     = [each.value.address]
```